# Autocomplete searchkick with synonyms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a Capture model which uses [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick):

```
class Capture < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchkick  autocomplete: ['name'],
              synonyms: [["scallion", "green onion"], ["qtip", "cotton swab"]]


end
```

I'd like to do a search by name (autocomplete) in the Capture model so I tried this in console:

```
Capture.search("scallio", autocomplete: true, limit: 10)
```

In my DB I have one Capture with the name "scallion" and one other with "green onion".

I would have expected that the above search return 2 elements thanks to the `synonyms` option but it returns only one item.

Maybe I misunderstood the `synonyms` option, or did I miss something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete does not take synonyms into account at the moment. I'll add a note to the readme.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for the response. Is it a searchkick or elasticasearch issue? If it is a searchkick issue do you want me to add an issue to the github repo?

Comment: With how autocomplete works, this isn't easy to do as far as I know.

Comment: I saw this article http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/you-complete-me/ this morning. They mentioned autocompletion working with synonyms. I do not know if it can help.